# I built a simple vuejs app with vuex but I would like to use mapGetters, how can I implement that function on it?

Tags: vuex

I built a simple vuejs app with vuex but I would like to use mapGetters, how can I implement that function on it?

this is my index.js:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    counter: 0,
    colourCode: 'blue'
  },
  getters: {
    counterSquared(state){
      return state.counter * state.counter
    }
  },
```

and currently this how the vue component looks like:

```
    <template>
      <div class="home">
        <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
    <div
        :style="{color: $store.state.colourCode}"
       class="counter">
      {{$store.state.counter}}
    </div>
    <div class="counter-squared">
      {{$store.state.counter}}
      <sup>2</sup> =
      {{$store

.getters.counterSquared}}
</div>
```

How can I change it to using mapGetters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do, in `VUE 3`

```
<script>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
export default {
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()

    return {
      counterSquared: computed(() => store.getters.counterSquared)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Using setup template :

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
    const store = useStore()
    const counterSquared: computed(() => store.getters.counterSquared)

  }
}
</script>
```

`Vue 2`

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  // you can call it like this.counterSquad, counterSquad(in template)
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'counterSquared',
      // ...
    ])
  }
  // OR
  // you can call it like this.cS, cS(in template) base on defined name.
  computed: {
     ...mapGetters({
        cS: 'counterSquared'
     })
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```